# Navigation Drawer is not handling click events

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Problem 1- My navigation drawer is not handling click events.

Problem 2- Instead of showing hamburger icon it is showing backward arrow.

I tried searching already but couldn't find answer. I also tried adding .bringToFront() method but still not working.

**MainActivity.java:-**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TextView navUserName = findViewById(R.id.textViewNav_username);
        TextView navUserEmail = findViewById(R.id.textViewNav_useremail);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference volunteerRef = dbRef.child("Volunteer").child(currentUser.getUid());
        //If current user is null go to login activity
        if (currentUser == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }


        //Creates hamburger animated icon
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        //Sets click listner to navigation item 1/2
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.bringToFront();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_option_home);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_option_profile, R.id.nav_option_contact, R.id.nav_option_about, R.id.nav_option_share,R.id.nav_option_logout)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    }

    //Sets click listner to navigation item 2/2
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("main1122", "inside listner");
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_option_home:
                Log.d("main1122", "Clicked item" + item.getItemId());
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_nav_drawer,
                        new HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_option_profile:
                Log.d("main1122", "Clicked item" + item.getItemId());
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_nav_drawer,
                        new profile()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_option_contact:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_nav_drawer,
                        new contact()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_option_about:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_nav_drawer,
                        new AboutFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_option_share:
                //TODO: Share app action
                Toast.makeText(this,"Share clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_option_logout:
                //TODO: Logout action
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        //Return false will make menu item unselected(not highlighted)
        return true;
    }
```

**activity_main.xml** (Contains R.id.nav_view) :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_nav__drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav__drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_nav__drawer_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**mobile_navigation.xml** (Contains fragments which I want to launch after clicking menu items) :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.helpinghandsorg.helpinghands.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:name="com.helpinghandsorg.helpinghands.AboutFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_about"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_about_to_nav_home"
            app:destination="@id/nav_home" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
        android:name="com.helpinghandsorg.helpinghands.ui.contact.contact"
        android:label="@string/menu_contact"
        tools:layout="@layout/contact_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_contact_to_nav_home"
            app:destination="@id/nav_home" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:name="com.helpinghandsorg.helpinghands.ui.profile.profile"
        android:label="@string/menu_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/profile_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_profile_to_nav_home"
            app:destination="@id/nav_home" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

**activity_nav_drawer_drawer.xml** (Contains Menu Item IDs):-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navi_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_option_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_option_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_option_contact"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_contact" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_option_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_about" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_option_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="@string/menu_share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_option_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_logout" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Please don't link to your code off-site. You need to provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: You're set up to use the Navigation component, but also trying to handle navigation yourself. If you mean to be using the Navigation component, then you shouldn't be trying to handle the `NavigationView` and `FragmentTransaction`s yourself; the component will handle those for you, as well as the hamburger/arrow button. If you'd rather do it the old fashioned way, then you should get rid of all of the Navigation stuff, because that's overriding your `NavigationView` and `ActionBarDrawerToggle` setup above it.

Comment: I managed to fix it by removing the additional code for manually handling navgation, but still on ONLY home fragment it is showing back arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for my 2nd question.
PROBLEM- Instead of showing hamburger icon it is showing backward arrow.

Solution- Actually it was because I didn't provide ID of home fragment on my **AppbarConfiguration.Builder**

Before-

```
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_option_profile, R.id.nav_option_contact, R.id.nav_option_about, R.id.nav_option_share,R.id.nav_option_logout)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
```

After-

```
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_home,
                R.id.nav_option_profile, R.id.nav_option_contact, R.id.nav_option_about, R.id.nav_option_share,R.id.nav_option_logout)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
```